# Error al intentar iniciar sesión en heroku

Tags: python, aplicación-web, flask, heroku

Quiero subir mi proyecto realizado con Flask a Heroku.

[image: directorio de archivos]

ya realicé el proceso de init con git, pero al momento de tratar de iniciar sesión con heroku para poder desplegarlo me aparece el siguiente error:

```
C:\Users\my_user\my_proyect>heroku login
 »   Warning: heroku update available from 7.53.0 to 7.64.0.
heroku: Press any key to open up the browser to login or q to exit:
Opening browser to https://...
Logging in... done
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:/Users/my_user/_netrc'
```

El problema es la última línea:

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:/Users/my_user/_netrc'
```

¿A qué se debe ese error y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: es un error de permisos, ese archivo en windows es equivalente al [`.netrc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/manual/html_node/The-_002enetrc-file.html) de otros sistemas, proba moverlo o crear uno vacío si no existe